# Как избавиться от непечатаемых символов в списке

Tags: python, list, unicode

Есть такой список с такими значениями

```
x = [['\ufeffstring1', '\ufeffstring2', 123], ['string3', 'string4', 123], ['string5', 'string6', 123]]
```

Как избавиться от непечатаемых символов

```
x = [['string1', 'string2', 123], ['string3', 'string4', 123], ['string5', 'string6', 123]]
```

Comment: `'\ufeffstring1'.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode()`- получится `string1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[''.join(filter(str.isascii, j)) if isinstance(j, str) else j for j in i] for i in x]
```

На выходе:

```
[['string1', 'string2', 123],
 ['string3', 'string4', 123],
 ['string5', 'string6', 123]]
```

Comment: Можно на самом деле сдекодировать `[[j.encode('utf-16le').decode('utf-16') if isinstance(j, str) else j for j in i] for i in x]`. А то вдруг там реально Unicode.

Comment: @GrAnd Да задача в целом довольно расплывчато поставлена )

Comment: Всем спасибо, работает. Да у меня есть кириллица в списке.

Answer (score 0):

Если текст файла считывается с диска, то можно попробовать выставить

```
open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

А так скорее всего через `string.replace()` в цикле по списку.